# Send a value from my module to invoice (make new invoice odoo8)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to make a button which send fields values from reservation.chambre and chambre  to account.invoice and  account.invoice.line .

- when i confirm the reservation is added  in account.invoice.
  -The field id_partner(class reservation_chambre)  > partner_id (invoice)
  -The field numch (class chambre) > name product ( invoice_ligne).
  -The field montant(class chambre) > price_unit ( invoice_ligne).
  -The field duration (class reservation_chambre) > quantity(invoice).

this my code

```
class reservation_chambre(osv.Model):

    _name = 'reservation.chambre'

    @api.multi
    def confirmer_reservation(self):
        """
        This method create a new recordset for hotel room reservation line
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        @param self: The object pointer
        @return: new record set for hotel room reservation line.
        """
        reservation_line_obj = self.env['reservation_line.chambre']
        for reservation in self:
            self._cr.execute("select count(*) from reservation_chambre as hr "
                             "inner join reservation_line_hotel as hrl on \
                             hrl.id_line = hr.id "
                             "inner join hotel_reservation_line_room_relation as \
                             hrlrr on hrlrr.numch = hrl.id "
                             "where (date_d_arrivee,date_de_depart) overlaps \
                             ( timestamp %s, timestamp %s ) "
                             "and hr.id <> cast(%s as integer) "
                             "and hr.state = 'confirmé' "
                             "and hrlrr.reservation_line_id in ("
                             "select hrlrr.reservation_line_id \
                             from reservation_chambre as hr "
                             "inner join reservation_line_hotel as \
                             hrl on hrl.id_line = hr.id "
                             "inner join hotel_reservation_line_room_relation \
                             as hrlrr on hrlrr.numch = hrl.id "
                             "where hr.id = cast(%s as integer) )",
                             (reservation.date_d_arrivee, reservation.date_de_depart,
                              str(reservation.id), str(reservation.id)))
            res = self._cr.fetchone()
            roomcount = res and res[0] or 0.0
            if roomcount:
                raise except_orm(_('Attention'), _('Vous avez essayé de confirmer la réservation avec une chambre qui est déjà réservé dans cette période !'))
            else:
                self.write({'state': 'confirmé'})
                for id_line in reservation.reservation_line:
                    line_id = id_line.reserver
                    for numch in line_id:
                        vals = {
                            'room_id': numch.id,
                            'check_in': reservation.date_d_arrivee,
                            'check_out': reservation.date_de_depart,
                            'state': 'assigned',
                            'reservation_id': reservation.id,
                            }
                        numch.write({'isroom': False, 'status': 'occupée'})
                        reservation_line_obj.create(vals)
        return True




    _rec_name = 'no_reservation'
    _columns = {  

        'no_reservation'  : fields.char('Reservation no', size=64, readonly=True, states={'brouillon': [('readonly', False)]}, copy=False),

        'id_partner': fields.many2one('res.partner','Client',required=True,help='le nom du client.'),
        'date_d_arrivee': fields.datetime("Date d'arrivée", size=64, required=True),
    'date_de_depart': fields.datetime('Date de départ', size=64, required=True),
    'Adultes':fields.integer('Adultes', help='Le nombre des adultes.' ),
    'enfants':fields.integer('Enfant',states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},  help='Le nombre des enfants.'),

    'date_order' : fields.datetime("Date d'aujourd'hui", required=True),


        'partner_invoice_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Adresse',
                                         readonly=True,

                                         help="Invoice address for "
                                         "current reservation."),
        'partner_order_id' : fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Ordering Contact',
                                       readonly=True,
                                       states={'draft':
                                               [('readonly', False)]},
                                       help="The name and address of the "
                                       "contact that requested the order "
                                       "or quotation."),
    'id_chambre': fields.many2one('room.gestion','Chambre'),


        'chambre': fields.one2many('room.gestion', 'numch', 'Chambre'),


    'state': fields.selection([('brouillon', 'Brouillon'), ('confirmé', 'Confirmé'),
                              ('cancel', 'Annulé'),  ('terminé', 'Terminé')],'Etat'),
    'reservation_line': fields.one2many('reservation_line.hotel', 'id_line',
                                       'Reservation',
                                       help='Hôtel détails de la réservation de la chambre.'),                      

    'date': fields.datetime('date'),
    'isroom': fields.boolean('isroom'),
    'duration': fields.float(string='Durée',
                            help="Nombre de jours sera automatiquement compter du date d'arrivée et date de départ."),
    'prix': fields.float('Prix'),
    'description': fields.text('Description'),

}   


    _defaults = {
       'date_order': lambda * a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
       'state':lambda * a:'brouillon',
       'no_reservation': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: '/',

        }




    _sql_constraints = [
        ('no_uniq', 'unique(no_reservation)', 'Numéro réservation doit étre unique! , choisissez un autre numéro svp'),
    ]





class reservation_line_hotel(osv.Model):
    _name = 'reservation_line.hotel'

    _columns = {
    'id_line': fields.many2one('reservation.chambre','Chambre'),


    'reserver': fields.many2many('room.gestion',
                               'hotel_reservation_line_room_relation',
                               'numch', 'reservation_line_id'),



}
reservation_line_hotel()

class chambre(osv.Model):
    _name = 'room.gestion' 

    _rec_name = 'numch'
    _columns = {

        'name': fields.char('Name'),              
        'photo': fields.binary('photo'),             
        'nom': fields.char('Nom'),  
        'numch'  : fields.char('Chambre', size=64),
        'capacite': fields.char('Capacite', size=64,required=True),
    'montant' : fields.float('Prix',size=64),
    'etage': fields.many2one('etage.gestion','Etage',required=True),
        'etat': fields.selection((('n','Occupée'), ('c','Disponible')),'Etat'),
        'datedecreation': fields.date('Date de création'),
        'description': fields.text('Description'),
    'service_id': fields.one2many('services.hotel','service_id','Service'),
    'room_reservation_line_ids' : fields.one2many('reservation_line.chambre',
                                                'room_id',
                                                string='Ligne de réservation chambre'),



        'status':fields.selection([('disponible', 'Disponible'),
                               ('occupée', 'Occupée')],
                              'Status', default='disponible'),
        'categorie': fields.many2one('categorie.chambre','type'),
    'color': fields.integer('couleur'),


}




    _sql_constraints = [
        ('numch_uniq', 'unique(numch)', 'numero chambre doit étre unique!'),
    ]
chambre()
```

Comment: Can you please give us some more info? How will you find the right invoice for the reservation? Describe the process behind this all in more detail. And: pls don't use direct queries but instead the orm layer of odoo (default methods like search, read, etc.)

Comment: thank you for your response
I want when I click on confirm a draft invoice bill will create or quotation (sale order).

-The field id_partner(class reservation_chambre) --> partner_id (invoice).\\\
-The field numch (class chambre) > name product ( invoice_ligne). \\\
-The field montant(class chambre) > price_unit ( invoice_ligne).\\\
 -The field duration (class reservation_chambre) > quantity(invoice).
or draft  Sale order with the client and command line